# BackgroundWorker, Methods

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

So putting the standard background worker crap aside. i was looking into how i can use the background worker a little more than (Worker DoWork { add some commands for it to do })

So this is what i have come up with so far. in this scenario its doing some random WMI stuff

View/ViewModel/Model
The model is called ManagementModel

```
    public void Start(String Args)
    {
        if (!Worker.IsBusy)
        {
            //Objectivly here you can spawn an instance of a class and perform a method.. or put the function in the background worker itself depending on what you want the thing to do
            ManagementModel BackgroundManagementTask = new ManagementModel();
            Worker.RunWorkerAsync(BackgroundManagementTask); //Starts the background worker.
            //If you specify the class to shove into the background worker, you need to put the commands of what to do in the DoWork section.
        }
    }
```

I have a methods and whatever in the  class that was spawned in the Start Method
here is the method for the DoWork

```
    private void Workers_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs Args)
    {
        //This is run on a completly seperate thread, you cannot make any changes to anything outside in this method.
        //you instead pass data through the Args.ReportProgress or Args.Result
        if (Worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            Worker.ReportProgress(100, "Cancelled By User");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //if you passed a method here, you will need to convert Args.Arguments back to what ever you passed it in as
            ManagementModel Internal = Args.Argument as ManagementModel;

            //bunch of stuff in the class that already works
            Internal.ComputerName = System.Environment.MachineName;
            Internal.Connect();
            Internal.ChangeWmiLocation("cimv2",null);
            ManagementObjectCollection ResultCollection = Internal.Query("Win32_Process");
            ClassProperties ResultProperties = Internal.DisplayProperties;

            //now return the results to the program thread
            Args.Result = ResultProperties;
            //now you need to deal with the data in the WorkerCompleted Event

            Worker.ReportProgress(100, "Completed");
            Thread.Sleep(60); //this is required at the end of each iteration of function
        }
    }
```

So my simple questions are.

1. is this concept possible, can i initiate an instance of a whole class and throw it into the background worker and have the background worker perform methods and functionality inside the class
2. if i have to pass data back to the UI. do you think that a Struct would be the best way to go.
3. How would i let the ViewModel know that the Background worker is completed and update the its exposed properties for the view to update.

or am i way off base ?

Comment: Is this a web app? Bad idea/design to use multi-threading in a web app...

Comment: Take a look at the task parralel library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the concept is possible. You can basically have a background worker do and access anything that you can do and access outside of the background worker's methods; the crucial point is that no two threads should be working with objects that haven't been explicitly laid out for that at the same time, which is why for example you should not access your UI from the background worker's working thread (the UI usually constantly being used by internal methods of the UI thread as well).
2. Whether you use a struct or a class is irrelevant with respect to threads; it is not the data that belongs to a given thread, but the operations. The only difference could be that when passing a struct, a copy of that struct would be created and you could keep working with your struct variable in the background worker thread - but even then, the same is true for a method that invokes callbacks within its own thread before further modifying a local struct/object, so this decision is really not related to threading.
3. Invoke a UI method that causes the updates to the UI once the background worker has completed its work and *make sure it is called on the UI thread*. The latter part can be accomplished by various means, depending on the UI toolkit the UI controls may offer a dispatcher object or something like that that allows synchronizing calls with the UI thread.

Comment: sweet. nice to know i wasnt too far off, i wrote the concept hoping it would be usable. my issue is that my background worker and my view model/view are seperated. hypothetically. if i use an interface. and had that same exposed property in the view model as in the background worker class, would this update my bound property thus updating the view ?

Comment: @NewBee: I am not sure I understood how you want to connect the property from the background worker and the view-model, but any calls to your view-model that will cause a binding evaluation in the UI essentially mean that you access the UI, irrespective of whether you access the property via an interface that the view-model implements or not. Hence, you will need to synchronize any such call with the UI thread, lest undesirable things happen.

Comment: well, it would be that the Background worker class is initiated by the     ViewModel, so the ViewModel will be able to access any properties/methods that is in the BackgroundWorker class. but this doesnt appear to work the other way around. I can reclaim data from a exposed property in the backgroundworker class no problem. so how would my ViewModel know that the backgroundworker class has finished data collecting ?

Comment: @NewBee: Either design your background worker method in a way so it has a reference to the view-model and can invoke a method of the view-model at the end of its work, or have the view-model register such a method with the [`RunWorkerCompleted` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the background worker. In either case, you will have to make that view-model method threadsafe, i.e. ensure that it synchronizes whatever it does with the UI thread.